# How to get number of documents of a collection in Android Cloud firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Assume that I have a collection named "students" below:

- collection `students` has 3 fields:

  - name
  - age
  - status (0: passed, 1: failed, -1: not tested)

('status' field describles the student passed or failed or Notyet tested)

- The collection `students` has 1000 documents with different 'status'
- Now I want to get the count of students who [passed/failed/not tested] the exam
- And whenever 'status' of a student is updated 0/1/-1 then I will have to re-count.

How can I solve this?
I shouldn't query all data for everytime update because it will cause high cost. NOTICE that, I want to count base on the 'status' field.

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how you can solve but instead of a CollectionReference simply use a Query.

Comment: Actually the duplicated you mentioned is just related to when I add or delete a document. My question is different: assume I have 1000 documents (and I will NOT add/delete any document),I want to count the students with different 'status' fields

Comment: That's the exact same approach.